# How to find the angular acceleration (rotating reference frames)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

[image: Problem]
[image: Solutions]

If you chose the frame to rotate with $w_1$ instead of $w_2$, wouldn't the angular acceleration be

$w_2 \times (w_1 + w_2)$?

and it would have $+20 \jmath$ instead? Shouldn't the absolute acceleration be the same both ways? Am I missing something? I understand the angular acceleration formula to be the angular acceleration with respect to your frame plus the angular velocity of the reference frame with respect to the fixed frame cross the total angular acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to consider rotating frames you can easily get confused by the rotations and the notation. I struggled with this, until I decided to take a step by step approach when dealing with a serial chain of rigid bodies each with a relative rotation about a single axis. The key here is to move from the absolute rotations to relative rotations such that

$$ \begin{align} \vec{\omega}_1 & = \hat{x} \dot{q}_1 \\
\vec{\omega}_2 & = \vec{\omega}_1 + \hat{z} \dot{q}_2 \end{align} $$

where the relative (scalar) rotations are $\dot{q}_1 = 5$ and $\dot{q}_2= 4$. Now to differentiate the above you have to consider on which frame are the unit axes $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{z}$ rotating about. For each body the rotation axis moves with the previous body such that

$$ \begin{align} \dot{\hat{x}} & = \vec{\omega}_{ground} \times \hat{x} = 0 \\ \dot{\hat{z}} & = \vec{\omega}_1 \times \hat{z} = (\hat{x} \times \hat{z}) \dot{q}_1 \end{align}$$

So the rotational accelerations are

$$ \begin{align} \vec{\alpha}_1 &= \dot{\hat{x}} \dot{q}_1 + \hat{x} \ddot{q}_1 =0 \\
\vec{\alpha}_2 & = \vec{\alpha}_1 +\dot{\hat{z}} \dot{q}_2 + \hat{z} \ddot{q}_2 = (\hat{x} \times \hat{z}) \dot{q}_1 \dot{q}_2  \end{align} $$
since $\ddot{q}_1 =0$ and $\ddot{q}_2 = 0$ due to the constant rates. You will find that $\hat{x} \times \hat{z} = -\hat{y}$.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got those constraints from, where X' = w_ground x X = 0 and the one below it. I never learned that, I used beer's vector mechanics as a resource to learn this, and I've never seen those equations. Do you have a textbook i could find online as a resource for your method?

Comment: Look up [vector derivative on rotating frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame). The answer is $$ \frac{{\rm d}\hat{v}}{{\rm d}t} = \vec{\omega} \times \hat{v}$$ if the vector is constant and $$ \frac{{\rm d}\hat{v}(t)}{{\rm d}t} = \vec{\omega} \times \hat{v}(t) + \frac{\partial \hat{v}(t)}{\partial t}$$ if it is varying with time.

Comment: I think I get it a bit, but could you elaborate on those two constraints? You chose x first because it's the rotation connected to the wall right? The velocity of that frame has to be zero. Why does Z have to be w_1 x z?

Comment: I looked at the diagram and saw $\vec{\omega}_1$ rotating about $\hat{x}$ relative to the previous body (ground). Then I saw the second body rotating about $\hat{z}$ relative to the first body. The time derivative of $\hat{z}$ is $\vec{\omega}_1 \times \hat{z}$ because that is the movement of the previous body. See comment about on differentiation of vectors on moving frames.